# MySQL function, retrieving and manipulate datetime

Tags: mysql

I have developed a function that allows me to check if a given resource has been booked on the date entered.

This happens through two tables:
`Resources` and `Unavailabilities`.

**Resources** contains:

```
ID, Description, model, unavailability_id etc.
```

**Unavailabilities** contains:

```
id, start_date, end_date, resource_id.
```

We place the house where `Unavailabilities` has a reservation with start `2019-04-20` and end `2019-04-21.`

When I enter the dates eg: `start = 2019-04-20 and end = 2019-04-21`

I receive a series of results depending on whether a reservation is present or not, if present I will have start and end of unavailabilities with the date on which the reservation is present, it is possible to manipulate the end date, causing mysql to return the result + 1 day? or a week or a month?

I tried the function add_date (date, INTERVAL + DAY), but this adds the interval to the date entered to make the search, without manipulating the result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM lux.unavailabilities 
WHERE `resource_id` = 32 AND `end_date` = ADDDATE('2019-04-21 12:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: Please include sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the day to the statement conditions instead of statement results.

Try this, and take a look at the [SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

```
SELECT lux.id, 
       lux.start_date, 
       ADDDATE('2019-04-21 12:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS NEW_END_DATE, 
       lux.resource_id 
FROM lux
INNER JOIN unavailabilities
   ON lux. unavailability_id =  unavailabilities.id
WHERE unavailabilities .resource_id = 32 
  AND unavailabilities .end_date = '2019-04-21 12:00:00';
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I forgot to check the join, now it is ok. Thanks